# Meteor: check parameter for object or boolean

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm doing a check like this:

```
check(param, { x: Number, y: Number, x2: Number, y2: Number, w: Number, h: Number });
```

But `param` could also be `false`. How should I do the check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/match_test):

```
check(param, Match.OneOf(Boolean, { x: Number, y: Number, x2: Number, y2: Number, w: Number, h: Number }));
```